# UICollectionView reuses cells even if there are enough space in screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewlayout

I am facing a weird issue, UICollectionView reuses cells even if there are enough space in screen and not scrolled also.

I have only two cells in the iPad screen, still every time with reload data, cells getting reused alternatively like below

First time reload - First and Second Cells appear with address 0x00007ff3f2c1a8b0  and 0x00007ff3f2830040 respectively

on the same screen - Second time reload - cells appear with address 0x00007ff3f2830040 and 0x00007ff3f2c1a8b0 respectively.

Can any one help me understand for this behaviour of collection view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When you call dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:) method, you should always expect it to be reused. You cannot predict the order of the cell dequeue.

If you want to be prepared for it, use prepareForReuse() method.